# can't display data in table from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code I need to display months and days in a table. I am able to display months but I can't display days in my table (it contains two headers months and days).

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
  var doc = result[i];
  var td = $("<td/>").html(doc.Months).data(doc);
  var td2 = $("<td/>").html(doc.Days);
  var tr = $("<tr>").html(td).append('</tr>');
  table.append(tr);
}
```

```html
<table id="mydemo5" class="mytdemo5" style="display:none;border-collapse: collapse; border-color:white;" border="1">
 <tr><th colspan="2">Absence history </th></tr>
 <tr><th>Months</th><th>Days</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending only first `td`, not `td2`, better to do it this way:

```
var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo(table); // no need of closing tag, it will be auto handled by jQuery
var td = $("<td>").html(doc.Months).data(doc).appendTo(tr);  //No need to assign to var td if it doesn't have any other use
var td2 = $("<td>").html(doc.Days).appendTo(tr);

//table.append(tr) Not needed anymore
```